# Sending out lockdown or general message to all active users in domain, cross-architecture

Tags: powershell, citrix

I'm trying to setup a script which will message all users in domain - Mixture, some are on Windows 10 Surface Pro's, some Citrix VDI.

The Citrix Part at the bottom isnt quite right, when starting a session, i seem to need to import the Citrix modules to the DDC, even though i'm connect via a PS Session (new-pssession) to the controller. The message on the VDI users desktop isn't appearing and, not sure why...

```
      $Cred = Read-Host "enter-username e.g. domain\user.name" 
            $computers = Get-Content C:\Scripts\allcomputers.txt #| Where-Object { $_ } 

            #foreach ($computer in $computers) {


             #    Invoke-Command -computername $computer -scriptblock {msg * "INSERT MESSAGE TO STAFF HERE"} -Credential $cred

            }

           # Import-Module Citrix.XenDesktop.Admin?
           # Add-PSSnapin Citrix?


               $s = New-PSSession -cn DDC -Credential DOMAIN\Cred

               Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { $sessions = Get-BrokerSession -UserName DOMAIN\User ;
Send-BrokerSessionMessage $sessions -MessageStyle Information -Title TestTitle -Text TestMessage
               }

               Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

If i use the command in the script block in an interactive session, the modules don't appear to be installed, hence the commented out 2 lines... :S

Comment: Does the messages appear when you run it directly from the DDS ? Do you still run into the 'module not found" problem from the DDS?

Comment: It will run fine if i just run the module import and add the snapin directly from the DDC, it seems as though i need to somehow import those modules to the session from the remote machine, even though it should just run from the DDC as, thats where the session is started? Confused!

Comment: p.s. The module is already installed on the DDC, but when i connect via a PSSession, it is not installed? Do i have to import modules even when connected to a machine where they are installed during a Session?

Comment: If you need the modules and snap-ins in the remote session `$s`, you're going to have to import the modules and/or add the snap-ins in the `$s` session.  Loading them on your local session isn't going to impact the remote session in any way.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks dude, i managed to get it working in the end, i did try importing the module and adding the snap in's for Citrix and got an error before, this code worked in the end for the session to call the Citrix Cmdlets:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help - Working Code that will send out a message to all Citrix XDT sessions via PowerShell:

```
$s = New-PSSession -cn CitrixDDC -Credential Domain\Administrator

           Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { import-module 
           Citrix.XenDesktop.Admin; Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*; 

           $sessions = Get-BrokerSession -UserName Domain\* `

           Send-BrokerSessionMessage $sessions -MessageStyle Information -Title 
           TestTitle -Text TestMessage

           }

       Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```